# Text-based apps not working suddenly

Tags: macos, text-editor

I have several text editors that I use on my 10.9 machine, including TextEdit and Smultron. I also have other programs that can edit text, like Safari and Xcode.

In the last couple of days, all the text editors tight-loop on startup. Opening Smultron, for instance, makes the program menus appear instantly, but then that's it, it's locked up. You can't even use the menus. TextEdit is exactly the same.

Xcode works fine, however. So do other text editing apps like Safari, Mail, etc.

So to test this, I downloaded TextMate, which has never been on my system. It worked.

I *suspect* there is some sort of very large file, missing, damaged, etc., that both Smultron and TextEdit are attempting to re-open. But I can't figure out where that information might be stored so I can clear it out. Any clues?

Comment: try restoring your fonts using the font book in applications folder.

Comment: no luck, same thing on startup